# Возможно ли поместить такую конструкцию в класс?

Tags: c++

Возможно ли поместить такую конструкцию в класс?

```
constexpr size_t width = 10;
constexpr size_t height = 10;
const size_t buffer_size = width * height;
std::array<Color, buffer_size> image;
```

Comment: Почему сначала `constexpr`, а затем вдруг просто `const`? В чем идея?

Comment: Не очень хороший подход для  того, чтобы задать размер массиву

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помещаем

```
struct S
{
  static constexpr size_t width = 10;
  static constexpr size_t height = 10;
  static const size_t buffer_size = width * height;
  std::array<Color, buffer_size> image;
};
```

Или

```
struct S
{
  size_t width, height;
  size_t buffer_size = width * height;
  std::vector<Color> image = std::vector<Color>(buffer_size);

  S(size_t width, size_t height) : width(width), height(height)
    {}
};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Могу ли я каким то образом задавать значения для width и height через конструктор при создании объекта?

Comment: @Denver 313: При использовании `std::array` - нет. Почему используется именно `std::array`?

Comment: std::array используется для хранения цвета и позиции пикселя для рендеринга, на этом построена остальная часть кода,

Comment: @Denver 313: На чем именно "построена остальная часть кода"? Почему нельзя использовать `std::vector` вместо `std::array`?

Comment: такая замена возможна. Класс должен каким то образом вернуть контейнер размер которого задан через конструктор. при этом контейнер должен содержать в каждом индексе информацию о пикселе struct Color(цвет RGB) и координаторы (x,y)

Comment: @Denver 313: Это значит, что вам нужен `std::vector`, а не `std::array`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы)